# Spring-boot parse excel file or .csv file with using application.properties

Tags: excel, spring, maven, application.properties

I am developing one spring boot application.
Where I am having one input excel file. I have converted that file into .csv format.
Now I am accessing the columns by index values but I want to access them with using headers. With using application.properties how it is possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Got some code to show?

Answer (score 0):

You should create a enum of header name with index as value. Use this enum instead of index in your code.

```
public enum headers{
     col1(0), col2(1);
     private int index;
     public headers(int i){
            this.index=i;
       }
}

///Use like:

getColumn(headers.col1);
```